# Destructuring assignment cannot recognize a declared variable

Tags: javascript, destructuring

My origin test, try to assign 2 numbers to the object.

```js
let obj = {}
let num = 100
let tar = 200

[obj.num, obj.tar] = [num, tar]
console.log(obj)
```

There is a reference error that I can't figure out.

```
VM212:5 Uncaught ReferenceError: tar is not defined
    at <anonymous>:5:28
```

However next, stranger thing happen.

```js
let obj = {}
let num = 100
let tar = 200
let a 
let b
[obj.num, obj.tar] = [num, tar]
console.log(obj)
```

It logged successfully.

```
{num: 100, tar: 200}
```

Please help me out of this.

Comment: Do not omit semicolons from your statements if you're not clear about the rules.

Comment: Thank you. I will go study deeper about it.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a semicolon add the end of each line. This makes it easier for the JavaScript interpreter/compiler to understand what you mean.

```js
let obj = {};
let num = 100;
let tar = 200;

[obj.num, obj.tar] = [num, tar];
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: Thank you.
I will go study deeper about it.